# Adding a reduced array to a variable inside of a function?(js)

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

So I have an assignment, and I can only add code to certain lines, but I need to get the sum of the array and then have it returned. I used reduce but I don't know how to add it to the variable total while inside of the funtion, and i'm not allowed to change the value of total.

```
var shoppingCart = [20, 15];

function getTotalCost(prices){
  let total = 0;
 // code below

 shoppingCart.reduce((total, amount) => total + amount);

 // code above
  return total;
}

getTotalCost(shoppingCart);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like, you have more than one problem with your code:

1. You need an assignment or just return the value of [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).
2. I suggest to use a start value as well, because empty arrays throws an error by using `reduce`.
3. **Inside of the function `getTotalCost`, you need to use the handed over array `prices`, not the hard coded `shoppingCart` array.**

```js
function getTotalCost(prices) {
    return prices.reduce((total, amount) => total + amount, 0);
}

console.log(getTotalCost([20, 15]));
console.log(getTotalCost([]));
```

Comment: I don't think there's any need to bring in purity here, the three problematic points stand well on their own. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be

```
  shoppingCart.forEach(price => total += price)
```

Answer (score -1):

`total` in the `reduce` function doesn't have access to the `total` variable *declared outside* (`let total = 0`), it has its own scope and is limited to this callback array function, **hence its value doesn't get reflected once the `reduce` function has returned the output**.

**Demo**

```js
var shoppingCart = [20, 15];

function getTotalCost(prices){
  let total = 0;

 //this line prints 20 but that value is not reflected in total declared outside
 shoppingCart.reduce((total, amount) => (console.log(total), total + amount)); 

  return total;
}

console.log(getTotalCost(shoppingCart));
```

Simply save the returned value of `reduce` to `total`

```
 total = shoppingCart.reduce((total, amount) => total + amount);
```

**Demo**

```js
var shoppingCart = [20, 15];

function getTotalCost(prices){
  let total = 0;
 // code below

 total = shoppingCart.reduce((total, amount) => total + amount);

 // code above
  return total;
}

console.log(getTotalCost(shoppingCart));
```

Also, you can check if the array size is greater than 0 before `reduce`

```
 total = shoppingCart.length && shoppingCart.reduce((total, amount) => total + amount);
```

Comment: You're not using the `total = 0` value.

Comment: @Bergi Didn't get you. Where am I not using `total = 0` value and why was it required for this reduce function to work?

Comment: I think `getTotalCost([])` should use that initial value. Your code doesn't. Nina's answer is much better.

Comment: @Bergi Have a look a Nina's answer again, `total`'s isn't used there either and OP didn't asked for pure function as well.

Comment: @Bergi If you are referring to OP's sentence *but I don't know how to add it to the variable total while inside of the funtion* Nina's answer doesn't help there either.

Comment: Consider `return prices.reduce(…, 0)` as an obvious abbreviation for `let total = 0; total = prices.reduce(…, total); return total;`.

Comment: OP might not have asked for a pure function, but I'm pretty sure he expected a function that would not throw on an empty array. (And using `shoppingCart.length &&` instead of applying `reduce` properly is a *horrible* hack).

Comment: @Bergi But that doesn't answer OP's question on why he is not able to add value to `total`. And why is not using `reduce` if *array length is 0* not better than using `reduce` and handling *empty array* condition within `reduce`?

Comment: Yes, your first sentence with the explanation of why it doesn't work is valuable, but your suggested solution is not imo. And why would we introduce a special case for array length 0 if `reduce` is totally capable of handling that without any conditions?

Comment: @Bergi Because **1)** OP never mentioned which all boundary conditions needs to be handled. By that logic, shouldn't the conditions like **non-numeric values** be handled as well? **2)** Won't it be faster to return `0` rather than having `reduce` does the same thing?

Comment: 1) No, he didn't, that's why everyone would expect just an array of numbers. Not a special non-empty array of numbers. 2) I haven't measured what's faster, but using `reduce` is definitely simpler.